# I am having trouble understanding EM gradient algorithm can someone help?

Tags: computational-statistics, expectation-maximization

I understand the formula for the EM gradient algorithm but I don't understand what it means by taking one step of Newton's method. Does it mean that it just take one iteration to converge to the conclusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking one step in Newton's method means

1) Calculating the gradient $\nabla f$ and hessian $\nabla^2 f$ of the function $f$ being maximized at the current point $x_i$

2) Applying the update rule $x_{i+1} = x_i - (\nabla^2 f(x_i))^{-1} \nabla f (x_i)$ to get a new point.

You *stepped* from $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$.

Generally no, you are not done after one step.  You need to check to see if the change in the value of $f$, from $f(x_i)$ to $f(x_{i+1})$, is smaller than your convergence threshold, then you stop.

You are only guaranteed to stop in one step if $f$ is a quadratic function.

> Can xi be any arbitrary value? If the f(xi+1) does not meet the convergence threshold, what shall we do?

You do it over again.

In detail.  To begin you choose a point $x_0$ by any means, it could be randomly, you could start at $0$, really anything.  Then you compute $\nabla f (x_0)$ and $\nabla^2 f (x_0)$, and take a step:

$$x_{1} = x_0 - (\nabla^2 f(x_0))^{-1} \nabla f (x_0)$$

No we are at $x_1$, if $| f(x_1) - f(x_0) | < \epsilon$, we stop and return $x_1$ as our maximum.  Otherwise, compute $\nabla f (x_1)$ and $\nabla^2 f (x_1)$, then take another step:

$$x_{2} = x_1 - (\nabla^2 f(x_1))^{-1} \nabla f (x_1)$$

Now we are at $x_2$, if $| f(x_2) - f(x_1) | < \epsilon$  <sub><sup>we stop and return $x_2$ as our maximum.  <sub><sup>Otherwise, compute $\nabla f (x_2)$ and $\nabla^2 f (x_2),  <sub><sup>take another step...</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub>

Comment: Can xi be any arbitrary value? If the $ f(x_{i+1}) $ does not meet the convergence threshold, what shall we do?

Comment: @zxu7 I edited in an answer to your question.

Comment: @madrury How to choose $ \epsilon $? Is there some usual choices for it?

Comment: It's usually a rather arbitrary small number.  Common values are in the ballpark of .0001